# C# HTTP Post Curl issue

Tags: c#, json, http, curl

I am trying to post a specific HTTP Post however i am not understanding the conversion for C# to do this correctly, I feel like I am most of the way there but getting stuck along the way

This is what I am trying to send:

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"text": " Some text or a string in my case a string :tada:"}' http://example.com/hooks/KEYDATA
```

Should look something like this...

```
POST /hooks/KEYDATA HTTP/1.1
Host: http://example.com
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 63
```

Here is what I have....

```
           async Task sendRequest()
            {
                using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), 
"https://example.com/hooks/KEYDETAIL");
                request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");
                request.Content = new StringContent("{\"text\":\" " + questionCreated + "\" :tada:\"}", 
Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                MessageBox.Show(request.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: Why are you showing the request in the messagebox instead of the response? Is that intentional? You're not doing anything with the response.

Comment: In the request.Content you add an additional " directly before :tada: which is not in your curl example. Is this by accident?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to display the request instead of the response.

The response is of type [HttpResponseMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage?view=netcore-3.1)

You are displaying the request in the message box, not the response. Assuming you want to see the actual response stream, try the following, it reads the content as string:

```
MessageBox.Show(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent?view=netcore-3.1

With the HttpResponseMessage you're able to read multiple properties like the headers or status code.

---

### In order to debug such things, try to read the responses content and statuscode properties.

Another tip: I noticed you mannualy constructing a JSON string; using NewtonSoft you should be able to do just this:

```
string jsonstring = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { text = "tada" } );
```

---

Another tip, for me usualy the following suffies:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    //no need to set header
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://example.com/hooks/KEYDETAIL")
    {
        Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourobject),
                                    Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
    };

     var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
}
```

Comment: my messagebox works fine its the post that isnt working. :-(

Comment: It would help if you describe in detail what exactly is not working, for example what is the actual response? The status code and response should display information, or the call should throw an exception.

Comment: So that answer doesn't resolve the issue. the only response I am getting from the server is that it failed to parse my request. I was showing my request in an effort to see if i was sending the correct data.

Comment: @MichaelWilliams: hi, can you post the actual status code and response from the server or exception?

Comment: meanwhile, I'll try to recreate it in an actual project

Comment: {"id":"model.incoming_hook.parse_data.app_error","message":"Unable to parse incoming data","detailed_error":"","request_id":"KEYDETAIL","status_code":400}

Comment: Status is 400 bad request- which is basically the server telling you that the provided data in invalid. This means your data structure is not compliant with what the server is excpecting

Comment: @MichaelWilliams: can you compare the curl tring with the parsed json string? It's likely there is a difference between the two

Comment: also I am unable to use JsonConvert, what I am doing must be doable with standard .net libraries. Policy issues.

Comment: @MichaelWilliams That error would have definitely been something you should have included in your original question. It would have saved everyone a whole lot of time.

Comment: @MichaelWilliams: download this package, it's .net standrd compatible: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json Otherwise use an other json serializer.

Comment: @Stefan I tried your solution, it posted code errors even with the nuget request made and used.

Comment: what does the http endpoint expects it to be? it seems your sending incorrect data

Answer (score 1):

Your C# code generates a different/invalid json string than you provided in the curl call.

If you take

```cs
request.Content = new StringContent("{\"text\":\" " + questionCreated + "\" :tada:\"}", 
    Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

The resulting string will be (look at the additional *"* before *:tata:*).

```json
{"text":" Some text or a string in my case a string" :tada:"}
```

instead of

```json
{"text": " Some text or a string in my case a string :tada:"}
```

Replace it with

```cs
request.Content = new StringContent("{\"text\":\" " + questionCreated + " :tada:\"}", 
    Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Comment: actually: nice find :)